# Is there a way to pass in a variable as my class name when navigating to another class in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have three classes, let's call them A, B, and C, that all call one splash screen class, which then calls a class (that reads in a specific PDF). My user is currently able to choose class A, B, or C (from features on the screen that call the appropriate class), are then taken to the splash screen, and are then taken to the PDF class. I want to override the back button from this PDF class, and take them to the original class they chose (A, B, or C) instead of just back to the splash screen (which just shows a loading screen). In my PDF class, I have a variable called "className", which is shown in the code below. This variable contains a string of the correct class name (A, B, or C) as defined in my App.js file.

Sorry for the long explanation, I tried to make it as simple as possible. The code below is from my  App.js file, where I am trying to implement the return to grab the className variable (which is grabbed correctly when i do console.log). However, my issue occurs in the onPress() method. Unless I manually type in the class name as ('A', 'B', or 'C') as a string like this **navigation.navigate('A')**, the program will not extract the string from my variable className and will just not do anything if I press the back button. Is there a way to correctly grab the string value from the variable className and put it in the onPress method and navigate to the correct class? I tried JSON.stringify() as well. Please let me know.

```
PDF: {
      screen: PDF,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        console.log(navigation.getParam('className'))
        var className = navigation.getParam('className');
        return {
          className : navigation.getParam('className'),
          headerLeft:(<HeaderBackButton onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate({className})}}/>),
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        }
      },
    },
```

Comment: Moving to another page or 2 screens on the same page?

Comment: there are 3 screens in total, if I press screen A, i then go to the loading screen, then to the PDF screen. When I press back on the PDF screen, I want to go to screen A, not the loading screen. I want to pass in the class name though to see what the user selected and navigate to the appropriate screen. Please let me know if that helps clear up things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved my own question. Essentially what I did was implement 3 if statements in my function that check the class name, and based on that class name, I return the headerLeft that navigates to the appropriate screen. I'll keep my question and post my solution below in case someone has the same problem or wants a similar solution:

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
            const getName = () => { 
              var screenName = ''
              screenName = navigation.getParam('className');

              if(screenName.includes('A'))
              {
                return {
                  headerLeft:(<HeaderBackButton onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('A')}}/>),
                  gesturesEnabled: false,
                }
              }
              else if(className.includes('B'))
              {
               ...
              }
```

And at the end of navigationOptions I just call the function getName() in my return statement. It's probably not the prettiest code or the most efficient way to solve this, so if you guys have suggestions please let me know.